# MYSQL Find Value in Table that Matches Best of Multiple Possible Sub Strings of a String

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with all municipalities in the State of Florida. As in many states, we have cities with the same root name, but are uniquely identified by direction. For example, we have a city called "Palm Beach" and we have a completely different city called "West Palm Beach".

[image: sample screen shot of municipalities table]

I have a string pulled from an .xls file that looks like this:

**3333 10TH ST., N. #201, WEST PALM BEACH, FL 34103**

I want to split the string into two segments, and segment #2 should begin with WEST PALM BEACH. Because if I can identify the city, then it will be easy to split segment #2 into CITY/STATE/ZIPCODE.

I (meaning PHP) don't really know where the city occurs in this string (which is part of my problem, as the string segments are different from string to string--some have commas, others don't have commas, so I can't really rely on comma delimiting to identify substring segments).

For example, the spreadsheet might just as easily have a line that looks like this:

**3333 10TH ST., N. #201, WEST PALM BEACH FL 34103** (notice missing comma).

This is why I want to search a table to match a city substring, because I can't trust the results of comma delimiting or space delimiting a string to get the final three parts of a substring, CITY STATE ZIP.

I need to definitively match WEST PALM BEACH but not PALM BEACH from the table.

How can I use my table of municipality names to identify that the city in the string is "WEST PALM BEACH" and not "PALM BEACH"?

Comment: Is the zip code always the last value? I'd do a look up on that for the city name.

Comment: @chris85 The zip code is always the last part of the string. I could use a zip code lookup, but that opens up a whole can of worms! Zip code lookups are historically in a state of flux. But the suggestion has strong merit. I'm going to research that, it may be a solution.

Comment: @chris85 Well, the zip code lookup just may be THE answer here.

Comment: Or... is the comma just missing between the city and the state? Possible regex approach, https://regex101.com/r/jK7sM3/1. If those are the only the deviations.

Comment: @chris85 I have 25,000 records, and the way the addresses are entered into the field is unreliable. Some separate city and state with a comma, some don't. So I have to find a reliable way of picking out the last three segments: city state zip code. I thought I should search for the city substring, but thanks to you I downloaded a zip code lookup with city & county. The zip code is ALWAYS the last segment, and I think that is THE solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is non-normalized I would just pull the zip code from the end of the string and do a look up on that. You can pull the zip code from  the end of the string with a regex like:

```
/(\d{5}(?:-d{4})?)$/
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jK7sM3/2 (if the zips will always be US, international zips vary in structure; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes)

Alternatively if the street part of the address consistently ends with a comma you could use:

```
\h([A-Z ]+)[,\h]+([A-Z]{2})\h+(\d{5}(?:-d{4})?)$
```

Which will should match the city, state, and zip code.

Demo 2: https://regex101.com/r/jK7sM3/1

Comment: Studying the regex example, but in the meantime working with a zip code look up. Fortunately, free zip code/city/county tables are freely available.